# How to read C++ code or: What to do without documentation?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, lapack

The question might sound a bit weird: I want to do numeric matrix calculations using Boost's ublas and ATLAS/Lapack. I am using the [Boost numeric bindings](http://mathema.tician.de/software/boost-numeric-bindings) to interface between those two libraries. However, either I just cannot find it or there is no proper documentation on how to use these bindings. Also, I am new to Boost (and actually C++ in general) so I have a hard time finding out how I can use functions provided by Lapack in my code.

The problem I want to solve in the end, is finding the Eigenvalues and -vectors of a symmetric banded matrix. As far as I understood it, I would be using `lapack::steqr` for this. The thing is, I don't know, how to properly call the function. In the code of the numeric bindings, I can see something like this:

```
template <typename D, typename E, typename Z, typename W>
inline
int steqr( char compz, D& d, E& e, Z& z, W& work ) {

  int const n = traits::vector_size (d);
  assert( traits::vector_size (e) == n-1 );
  assert( traits::matrix_size1 (z) == n );
  assert( traits::matrix_size2 (z) == n );
  assert( compz=='N' || compz=='V' || compz=='I' );
  ...
```

Now, how do I handle that? I tried `steqr<double, double, double, double>(...)` and double arrays, which didn't work. Then, to find out the proper arguments to use, I picked one of the asserts and tried to find anything that works with `traits::matrix_size1(...)` - Even that I couldn't get to compile, neither with a double array nor with a `ublas::matrix`.

So my question is, in general: When I find such a library without complete documentation, how do I find out how to call functions? I am coming from C mainly and am extremely confused with all these templates. Is the only way really to track down everything in the code? Or are there little tricks? Or can I probably draw information from the error messages?

One example of such an error message is, for the following code:

```
ublas::matrix<double> empty(N,N);
std::cout << traits::matrix_size1<ublas::matrix>(empty) << std::endl;
```

Then I get during compilation:

```
eigenvalues.cpp:40:85: error: no matching function for call to ‘matrix_size1(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double, boost::numeric::ublas::basic_row_major<>, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<double, std::allocator<double> > >&)’
eigenvalues.cpp:40:85: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/boost/numeric/bindings/traits/matrix_traits.hpp:148:18: note: template<class M> std::ptrdiff_t boost::numeric::bindings::traits::matrix_size1(M&)
```

It is probably useful, that the candidate is listed there, but I just don't know, how to read this line and adjust my code accordingly.

Again: This question is a bit more general, on how to deal with stuff like this. I know the basic concept of classes and templates, but this is just a bit too abstract for my knowledge.

Comment: In general there is no need to explicitly specify the template arguments to functions when the function paramater types can be deduced from the function arguments. This means that, for example, you can just call `matrix_size1` as `matrix_size1(empty)`. The reason that your original code does not compile is that you are passing a template (`ublas::matrix`) as the template argument, rather than a class (the correct type in this case is `ublas::matrix<double>`).

Comment: As for your original question - the only way to do this is to have significant experience with the language and to apply some inspired guesswork about the types of the parameters. An alternative might be to simply avoid poorly documented libraries.

Comment: I did figure it out, though, mainly due to luck while experimenting. Also, what helped a lot, was that with the library came a test/ directory where all functions are tested, providing a sample implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am not too proficient in templated c++, I personally find it much easier to use the `cblas` interface which is only a thin wrapper over the original Fortran code.

In this approach, you'll have to make your own class for matrices, which would be compatible to the Fortran understanding of what a matrix is. The easiest way is probably to inherit from `std::vector` or `std::valarray` and provide your own indexing operation. 
Yes, it's a bit of work.  But it's not as bad as it sounds :-).

And by the way, beware of using the single-precision routines (`ssteqr`) with double precision arguments. LAPACK will not report any error, but the result is going to be plain wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am in fact using double precision, but I hope that the boost numeric bindings choose the correct algorithm to suit my needs. I mean, that is partly what they are for, right? I will at some point compare my results with the analytic one, so I will see then if it is correct. However, as I said, I figured out how to use that stuff and I will post it later.